# Codeigniter save_queries showing queries only from default database group.How to show all queries from all database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**this is my config in database.php along with other array values i enabled save_queries**

```
$active_group   =   'mydb1';
$db['mydb1']    = array(
'save_queries' => TRUE);
==========================
$db['mydb2'] = array(
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

**this is my code to display.**

```
$queries = $this->db->queries;

foreach ($queries as $query)
{
echo '<br>'.$query;
}
----------
$this->db1   = $this->load->database('mydb2', TRUE);
$queries1 = $this->db1->queries;
foreach ($queries1 as $query1)
{
echo '<br>'.$query1;
}
```

**First foreach is working fine and displaying all queries from active group but second foreach is not showing any records.How to display all queries from all databases**